# typescript react props validation not working

Tags: typescript, react-typescript

I am new to typescript and can't seem to figure out the issue. I have created an interface and checking the props. its is working if props is empty but I am expecting a string and if number is passed it is not giving any error.

```
type Props = {
  name: number;
};

const ProductListItem = ({ name }: Props): JSX.Element => {
  return (
    <div className="product">
      <h4>{name}</h4>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProductListItem;
```

Using the Component here like this

```
    import "./ProductList.scss";
import ProductListItem from "./ProductListItem";

interface Product {
  _id: string;
  itemName: string;
}
type Props = {
  allProducts: Array<Product>;
};

const ProductList = ({ allProducts }: Props): JSX.Element => {
  console.log(allProducts);
  const productsTodisplay = allProducts.map((product: any) => (
    <ProductListItem key={product._id} title={product.itemName} />
  ));
  return <section className="productsContainer">{productsTodisplay}</section>;
};

export default ProductList;
```

Comment: Could you provide where you import your `ProductListItem`? and how do you test the prop types?

Comment: I am not checking the propTypes, I thought If I set the type in the interface and pass some other value it would throw error?

Comment: Try my answer, if it throws errors. It should be if you not giving any props or wrong prop types.

Comment: Which code editor are you trying this on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **For a proper type checking in `React Functional Component` you could add its type to `generic type parameter`**

Something like this:

```
import React, { FunctionComponent } from "react";

type Props = {
  name: number;
};

const ProductListItem: FunctionComponent<Props> = ({ name }) => {
  return (
    <div className="product">
      <h4>{name}</h4>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProductListItem;
```

Comment: Does it help? @special3220?

Comment: Yes, This approach also works. Also, I found what was wrong with my code, when I was mapping over all the products I set (product: any). When I removed it, it started working

Comment: Super! You could consider marking this accept if it is helpful for you and others who find this.